# Hi,I'm trying to build a program that will take a arraylist of integers & find the average&print it

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, average

This is the code I'm trying to make and so far the only two errors are in the main method and I'm trying to call the other methods from here that's whats giving me the errors please Help. what do i need to do to fix this issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> userNumbers = getInput();
    double avg = average(arrayList <integerList>);//error calling a method
    printAverage(avg, integerList);// error calling a method
}
public static ArrayList<Integer> getInput() {
    ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 5 to 10 positive integers all on one line, 
    seperated"
        + " by spaces; enter q to quit data entery:");
    integerList.add(in.nextInt());
    return integerList;
    }// getting the numbers for the array list
    public static double average(ArrayList<Integer> integerList){
    double avg = integerList.stream().mapToInt(val -> 
    val).average().getAsDouble();

    return avg;
    }//calculating the average
    public static void printAverage(ArrayList<Integer> integerList, double avg) 
 {
    System.out.println("The average of the numbers " + integerList + " is " 
    + avg);
 }//printing the average
```

Comment: You say *the only two errors* and *giving me the errors*, but you don't include what the *errors* are you're getting. That information is on the screen, right in front of you; there is absolutely no reason for you not to include it so we have it as well. Knowing what the *errors* are makes it much easier for us to answer your question, and the information is *right on the screen in front of you*.

Comment: This is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Add a tag for the language you are using.

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve], I doubt you need all 24 lines to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Double avg = average(userNumbers);

printAverage(userNumbers, avg);
```

That's the two errors fixed that you have highlighted in the `main()`

Comment: No probs, watch your parameters for methods

Answer (score -2):

In the main method, you are passing the parameter of average(arrayList ) but you just want to pass in the name of your Arraylist which would be userNumbers.
Same with printAverage(avg, integerList) should be printAverage(avg, userNumbers).

This is because you defined a local variable within main that goes by the name of userNumbers.

Comment: so when i changed the Average(integerList) to Average(userNumbers) the problem went away, however when I changed it for the printAverage(avg, userNumbers) i got a new error. the error was that a double couldn't be converted to an arrayList. but im not trying to do that.

Comment: Never mind I got it, thank you. very much appreciated.